# Android Adapter redrawing view with all the same original items rather than removing selected item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I've been trying to delete an item from my list so that it updates without the removed item, but the list seems to redraw itself and keeps displaying all the original items as before. For a short bit of time it's possible to see the item as if it's being removed, however, due to this redrawing everything gets back to what it was before the removal.

I've tried several combinations of the following methods but none of them seem to work in this case.

```
 adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, adapter.itemCount)
 adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)
 adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

These are my files. **Please notice I'm using the Groupie library as a replacement for the default RecyclerView.**

```
class RecyclerProductItem(
private val activity: MainActivity,
private val product: Product,
private val onItemClickListener: OnItemClickListener?
) : Item<GroupieViewHolder>() {

override fun bind(viewHolder: GroupieViewHolder, position: Int) {

    viewHolder.apply {

        with(viewHolder.itemView) {
            
            ivTrash.setOnClickListener {
                if (onItemClickListener != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "delete method to be added here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    onItemClickListener.onClick(viewHolder.adapterPosition)
 // deleteProduct(product.id)
                } 
            }


        }

    }
}


interface OnItemClickListener {
    fun onClick(position: Int) //pass your object types.
}


override fun getLayout() = R.layout.recyclerview_item_row

}
```

And here my fragment:

```
class ProductsListFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var adapter: GroupAdapter<GroupieViewHolder>


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_products_list, container, false)
}


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager

    adapter = GroupAdapter()
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter

    loadProducts()

}


/**
 * API calls
 */
private fun loadProducts() {

    GetProductsAPI.postData(object : GetProductsAPI.ThisCallback,
        RecyclerProductItem.OnItemClickListener {

        override fun onSuccess(productList: List<JsonObject>) {

            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "successful network call")

            for (jo in productList) {

                val gson = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create()
                val product: Product =
                    gson.fromJson(jo, Product::class.java)

                adapter.add(
                    RecyclerProductItem(
                        activity as MainActivity,
                        Product(
                            product.id,
                            product.title,
                            product.description,
                            product.price
                        ), this
                    )
                )

            }

        }

        override fun onClick(position: Int) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, position.toString())

            adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, 
adapter.itemCount)

            adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)

        }

    })

}

}
```

[image]

Many thanks.

Comment: You must remove the item from the list and then call adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)

Comment: Hi @dreamfire, thank you for your reply. Sorry, not sure I know how to access the exact item that needs to be removed and I'm a bit confused at this stage.

Comment: ```override fun onClick(position: Int) {

                cProductList?.toMutableList()?.removeAt(position)
                
                adapter.clear()
                
                for (p in cProductList!!) {
                    adapter.add(p)
                }

                adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, adapter.itemCount)
                adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)

            }
```

Comment: This gives me a compile error due to the item passed to the adapter, but it's something along this path you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Simple sample

```
class GroupAdapter(private val items: MutableList<Any>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

fun removeByPosition(position: Int) {
    items.removeAt(position)
    notifyItemRemoved(position)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this sample is for a normal RecyclerView. I'm using the Groupie library, and don't have a list available passed from a constructor this way.